# LTR and RTL in IONIC 4

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-translate in ionic 4 to add different languages. In my project I have arabic language. ngx-translate functionality is working fine. It is changing **dir** for html tag dynamically.

Problem:
I want to write some styles if html tag has **dir="rtl"** in each component. But angular has default encapsulation, So I am unable to write the styles as follows in my component.scss file.

```
html[dir="rtl"]{
  h3{
     color: red;
  }
}
```

I know that angular provides encapsulation change properties like,

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

But I don't want to use the advantage of encapsulation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any Solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes it's useful to apply styles based on some condition outside of a component's view. For example, a CSS theme class could be applied to the document `<body>` element, and you want to change how your component looks based on that.

[:host-context Full Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context)

Use the :host-context() pseudo-class selector, which works just like the function form of :host(). The :host-context() selector looks for a CSS class in any ancestor of the component host element, up to the document root. The :host-context() selector is useful when combined with another selector.

```
:host-context(html[dir="rtl"]) ion-card-subtitle {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this but it works correctly, have you noticed that the value is being added correctly to the `dir` attribute of the`html` tag?

I did the following test in my `component.scss` or in`global.scss` and it worked perfectly, maybe you are trying to write the styles of your `componentA` to your`componentB` and that is bringing you problems.

```
html[dir="rtl"]{
    ion-card-subtitle{
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to write the SCSS for components.

Comment: in case of dir="auto" ?